# How can use select2 multiselection but force it to open default browser multiselection box in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I use `select2` `jQuery` plugin in my web page and it works well even in mobile view but i want **force** it to show default browser multi selection box when i open the page by mobile browser and click on `select2` area to select multiple tags.

**Note:** by default `select2` open its list and bypass browser default selection box.

> I think browser default box has better responsive than `select2` when we want select multiple items from a drop down list.

- I **wont** fully remove `select2` capabilities when `max-width` of the page is `767px`.
- I **want** see nice selected tags in `select2` input area *(it's well now)*
  [image]

**But**

- I **want** see something like the following image in mobile just when click on `select2` input:

[image]

Comment: I can't find a custom override for select2 to bring up the device specific one. So unless you are going to try and create your own functionality on top of Select2, this might not be possible. But I only looked at the available methods in the documentation. There might be some feature I overlooked.